# How do I use mongoose models from my main app folder on another folder?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I found many examples, but I'm still quite confused on how to share one mongoose model in another folder. For example, let say I have a main folder and two subfolders. I want to share my App folder's mongoose model from app folder on admin folder, because these two folders will share the same mongodb Database

[image]

app folder's models

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const OrderSchema = new Schema({
  product: String
  created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Order', OrderSchema);
```

Any efficient way to share?

Answer (score -2):

you can see my github repos:- https://github.com/BhavikKheni/qoute-app.
i created schema in model folder and use in controller folder.